# Is there a Free IDE Plugin for extracting interfaces in vb.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, plugins

Is there a plug-in for the Visual Studio IDE that adds the feature available in C# for extracting interfaces from objects?

Comment: I assume you mean is there a plug-in which adds this feature to the VB.NET editor?  Does the VB.NET editor not have this?  You poor VB souls... ;-)

Comment: nope, sucks that it doesn't have it, especially for stuff like linqtosql objects.

Comment: Ah sorry, I was focused on the question body.  Didn't notice that you put 'VB.NET' in the question title.  Good luck - hope someone comes up with something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Refactor for VB](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/VBRefactor/) does this. It is also free.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/index.html#vb), it comes out of the C# world but it does support VB.Net now, and you can refactor a class to an interface with lots of other bells and whistles.

Comment: is there another option for something that doesn't cost $350?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370210/is-there-a-free-alternative-to-resharper - mostly oriented towards C# again though. Must be an opening for a slim/trim/resharper for $25?